# Asyncio and await issue (Discord bot)

Tags: python

Alright, so, I made a relatively small function for my bot to post messages from an API until the process at that API is complete and changes from one type of JSON code to another (that is, showing a different thing)

Gives me the following: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'discord_status_request' was never awaited`

And the code is as follows:

```
@client.command(name='addip')
async def discord_add_ip(ip):
    monitors.add(ip)
    await client.say('Added IP: {}'.format(ip))
    print(monitors)
    if len(monitors) < 2:
        discord_status_request()
        print('Initiating monitoring process.')


#@asyncio.coroutine
async def discord_status_request():
    global old_response
    global enablemonitoring
    for i in monitors:
        if enablemonitoring == True:
            while True:
                loop_break = False
                response = requests.get(url_input.format(i)).json()
                status_text = str("-" + "\n" + "Start year: " + str(response['start_year'])) + \
                              str('\n' + 'Start time: ' + str(
                              response['start_time'])) + \
                              str('\n' + 'Percentage: ' + str(response['percent'])) + \
                              str('\n' + 'Current year: ' + str(
                              response['current_year'])) + \
                              str('\n' + 'Scheme №: ' + str(
                              response['scheme_number'])) + \
                              str('\n' + 'Stop year: ' + str(response['stop_year']))
                new_response = response.get('percent')
                if new_response == old_response:
                    print('Comparison: nothing new.')
                    time.sleep(10)
                else:
                    old_response = new_response
                    print('Comparison success!')
                    try:
                        client.say(status_text)
                    except KeyError:
                        client.say("Finished calculating. :white_check_mark:")
                        if len(monitors) == 0:
                            loop_break = True
                        monitors.remove(i)
                print('Taking a break.')
                time.sleep(10)
                if loop_break:
                    break
```

I've looked the error up and found the following: https://xinhuang.github.io/posts/2017-07-31-common-mistakes-using-python3-asyncio.html

So I added this:

```
task = loop.create_task(discord_status_request())
loop.run_until_complete(task)  #(I imported AbstractEventLoop as loop)
```

But, you guessed it, create_task requires coro and run_until_complete requires future. I need coro and future. So what the hell are those? Can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to change depending on what version of python you are running.

but if your going to use the @asyncio.coroutine 
then you wont need to use the async keyword just do

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def discord_status_request():
   yield from function()
```

you would also use the yield from keywords so you may want to look up yield from with async.coroutine

other wise you should just do

```
async def discord_status_request():
   await function()
```

which is the way as of python 3.5

async def syntactically defines a function as being a coroutine, although it cannot contain any form of yield expression; only return and await are allowed for returning a value from the coroutine.

I think this is what your asking

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding.


I tried the 2nd method before, but it gave me the RuntimeError. Doesn't do that with @asyncio.coroutine method though.



But now it seems like it doesn't start the discord_status_request() when entering the command !addip what so ever. I've added a bunch of print lines in it, and it doesn't want to work at all :(

Comment: Yeah, it seems like @asyncio.coroutine doesn't let the function to work at all.